# when running a process on linux as root from tmp dir, process remembers dir and causes errors when dir is deleted

Tags: linux, root

I'm running a process on linux as root from a tmp dir (after extract). For some reason the process remembers the dir and when the dir is deleted I get errors

```
shell init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: no such file or directory.

** ERROR **: Resource problem creating '/tmp/app-selfextract.6bxSKU/orbit-root'
```

I've tried cd to another dir before activating the process but it didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code causing the problem?

Comment: What is the program you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Your process' current work directory is the directory that you are deleting. After you deleted this directory the process can not find information about it anymore (it can't even say what is the parent directory of the directory).

You say that you are try to change the current directory before starting the process. That's good, but it is possible that the process itself will change to the directory for some reason. It's hard to say, if it is really so not knowing anything about the process and that how you start it.

You can try to check if the process really has this directory as a current directory
using `/proc`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/24889/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 0 Jun 25 20:26 /proc/24889/cwd -> /tmp/so
```

(in your case you must write the pid of your process instead of 24889).